# vba error: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel

I'm getting a "object variable or with block variable not set" error message when running the following code. It is in Access and refers to an Excel spreadsheet. What is wrong with the code?

```
wsTest.Range("A11").Activate    

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    intX = intX + wsTest.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "L") 'error occurs on this line
    intY = intY + wsTest.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "I")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ' Step down 1 row to the next cell.
Loop
```

The first time the code is run, there is no error, only the second time. Closing and reopening Access "fixes" the problem. How can that be related to this code?

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: I updated the code above with that info.

Comment: ActiveCell refers to an Excel object, so you likely should qualify it with your XL application reference. Eg: xlApp.Activecell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error occurs in the highlighted line, I believe you're trying to do an invalid sum. Maybe the value returned by `wsTest.Cells(oCell.Row, "L")` isn't a integer, or you should use `wsTest.Cells(oCell.Row, "L").Value` instead.

Will be easier to identify the root cause of the problem adding a msgbox to check the cell value, as I added below.

Either way, I'd suggest you to avoid using references to ActiveCell, as they aren't reliable. Maybe this code helps avoiding this error (simply replacing the ActiveCell by a proper cell object).

```
Dim oCell as excel.range

set oCell = wsTest.Range("A11")

Do Until Len(oCell.Value) = 0
    msgbox(wsTest.Cells(oCell.Row, "L"))
    intX = intX + wsTest.Cells(oCell.Row, "L") 'error occurs on this line
    intY = intY + wsTest.Cells(oCell.Row, "I")
    Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0) ' Step down 1 row to the next cell.
Loop
```

Comment: It was an integer - ActiveCell was the problem. The messed up thing is that [Microsoft uses ActiveCell in their documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141762). Thanks very much for straightening that out!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the sheet, like so:

```
Dim wsTest As Worksheet

Set wsTest = Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it error on the line "wsTest.Range("A11").Activate" if that was the problem?

Comment: @Doug, that is what it was erroring on for me when I implemented his code, so I added those lines and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
wsTest.Range("A11").Activate
```

to

```
wsTest.Range("A11").Select
```

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address` before your `intX = ` line.  What's the result?

Comment: The first time the code is run, when the error does not occur, the result is $A$11, which is correct because the file I tested with only has one row of data. However, the second time the code is run, the error occurs on the `do until isempty(activecell)` line and `debug.print` never runs. So this is interesting, the error occurs the second time the code is run, on whatever line first tries to access the active cell. Hmm.